# Suppose $f=pg+q$ and either $q=0$ or $\deg(q) < \deg(g)$. Are $p$ and $q$ with these properties necessarily unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Given polynomials $f$ and $g$ nonzero in $K[x]$, Suppose that $f=pg+q$ and either $q=0$ or $\deg(q) < \deg(g)$. Are $p$ and $q$ with these properties necessarily unique?

Hello, I’m not really sure at all how to go about doing a proof or getting a counterexample for this. I think it has something to do with polynomial division however I’m not sure how I’d go about it at all. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume they are not unique, thus $f=p'g+q'=pg+q$. This implies $(p'-p)g=q-q'$ which means $q-q'$ is a divisor of $g$ but we know that $\text{deg}(q),\text{deg}(q')<\text{deg}(g)$ and consequently $\text{deg}(q-q')<\text{deg}(g)$. This means the only valid explanation is that both sides must equal zeros and since we asuumed $g\neq 0$, thus $p=p'$ and $q=q'$